# Windows Authentication not validating Roles

Tags: asp.net, security, windows-authentication

I am trying to limit access for a page like  so

```
<location path="ArticleAdministration.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
    <allow roles="domain\group"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

But for some reason when I login in with a user who does not have access to that group he is still possible to view the page.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong? Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another one rule right below rule for `domain\group`: `<deny roles="*"/>`, or even more explicit rule: `<deny users="*"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
<deny users="?" />
```

This is saying that all authenticated users have access to the page i.e. any user who can log in.

Then add below

```
<deny roles="*" />
```